# Return the deleted node in java RECURSIVELY

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I learned most of the linked data structures using C++ where there is pass by reference available to you and recursion is pretty straightforward. I recently switched to Java and I always get confused with the recursive versions of these structures.

I wanna take the node out of the list. But I want to return the node. When I return the deleted node from the `else if` branch, it expectedly messes up the list. But I can't see a way around it.

```
public node deleteval (int val){

        node prev = head;

        head = deleteval(head,prev,val);

        return head;
    }

 private node deleteval(node head,node prev, int val){

        if(head == null){

            return null;
        }
        else if (head.value == val){

            prev.next = head.next;
            node deleted = head;
            head = prev;


            return head.next;
        }

        prev = head;
        head.next = deleteval(head.next,prev,val);

        return head;
    }
```

This is not a homework, just trying to understand. Thanks for any input.

Comment: Would it help if I told you to think of a `node` in Java as a `node const &` in C++?

Comment: Also, as a reminder: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JoeC So... My only real option is to add the deleted node in some sort of stack structure and then pop that in the wrapper function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a node you only need to do `prev.next = head.next` and handle the edge case for `root` node. There is no need for a stack or any other supporting data structure, you simply recurse deeper into the list until you find the value or reach the end.

```
private Node root;

public Node deleteVal(int val) {
  return deleteRec(root, null, val);
}

private Node deleteRec(Node head, Node prev, int val) {
  if (head == null) {
    return null;
  } 
  if (head.value == val) {
    if (prev != null) { 
      prev.next = head.next; // deleting non-root node
    } else { 
      root = null; // deleting root node  
    }
    return head;
  }
  return deleteRec(head.next, head, val);
}
```